# UIImageView stopAnimation not working on viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to start imageView's animation on viewDidAppear phase.

I would like to stop animation when content of webview loaded on viewDidLoaded phase.

However my UIImageView does not stop animation when stopAnimation is called

on ViewDidLoaded phase.

can anybody tell me what should I do to stop animation on viewDidLoaded?

any help will be appreciated.

```
UIImageView *customActivityIndicator;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
    ...

    customActivityIndicator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(loadingPosX, loadingPosY, loadingImageWidth, loadingImageHeight)]; 
    [self.view addSubview: customActivityIndicator]; 
    customActivityIndicator.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],nil]; 
    customActivityIndicator.animationDuration = 1.0; // in seconds 
    customActivityIndicator.animationRepeatCount = 0; // sets to loop 
    [customActivityIndicator startAnimating]; // starts animating 
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ....
    [webView loadRequest : requestObj];
    [customActivityIndicator stopAnimating]; // stop animating  
}
```

Comment: Because viewDidAppear is called after viewDidLoad, you cannot stop animating in viewDidLoad. Try stopAnimating in UIWebViewDelegate method - `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **UIWebViewDelegate** and protocol method **webViewDidFinishLoad**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
 {
    [customActivityIndicator stopAnimating]; // stop animating  
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ....
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest : requestObj];

}
```